# Am I able to use "openssl/bn.h" in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Which framework i need to import to compile if i want to use openssl/bn.h
i am getting compilation errors ("referenced from") for all BN functions

please help

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is used internally on the phone, but the API is not supported for app development, and the symbols are not available to iPhone apps.

If you want to use openssl you will need to build it and statically link it with your app. That will also mean you you need to deal with export compliance. Yeah, I think it sucks too. If you think Apple should expose some particular OpenSSL functionality you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a feature request.